# How can we set Config parameters in spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, spree, spree-auth-devise

I am new to Ruby on Rails. I am building one e-commerce application using Spree .Can anyone tell me where all the config parameters are defined?
 for instance most of models and controllers use Spree::Config[:currency].I want to know where this parameter is actually defined?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at:

https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/v3.0.1/core/app/models/spree/app_configuration.rb

and related classes like:

https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/v3.0.1/core/app/models/spree/preferences/configuration.rb